# How to ensure parent component passes the same prop function to child to avoid rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Currently I have a two component set up, where the parent renders some data and handles retrieval and the child is a filter. This filter allows the user to filter by status or keyword. Nothing fancy.

Now this is a paginated system. After the parent makes an initial request for data, they're given the next page ID to request if they want more. But if the filter is updated, this next page ID needs to be wiped out, as it's no good.

So what I do is pass a function from the parent to the child called `updateFilter()`. If the filter component has an update in state, it calls up to the parent and runs `updateFilter()`. One of the values updated is included in a `useEffect()` dependency array, so the parent then requests the new data with the new filters. Easy.

The problem is in setting up the child's `useEffect()`. Eslint tells me I need to add `props.updateFilter` to the dependency array, and while I can just ignore this, I feel that it would be wrong to do so. But the parent has a fair bit of state that will update, and when it does, it passes a new copy of `updateFilter()` down into the child which causes it to incorrectly trigger.

How do I go about fixing this? Can I tell the child to only use a static version of this function somehow? Or do I just exclude `props.updateFilter` from the dependency array? Below is a rough psuedo code of my components.

```
Parent {
    const [stateVal, setStateVal] = useState(...);
    
    function updateFilter(filterStatus) {
        ...
        setStateVal(filterStatus);
    }

    useEffect(() => ..., [stateVal]);

    return <Child updateFilter={updateFilter} />
}

Child {
    const [filterStatus, setStatus] = useState(...);

    useEffect(() => {
        props.updateFilter(filterStatus);
    }, [filterStatus] // Adding `props` here is what I think I should do, but that causes the issue. Apparently the `props` val changes every time Parent's state changes
   
    return ( ... );
}
```

Comment: "Eslint tells me I need to add `props.updateFilter` to the dependency array, and while I can just ignore this, I feel that it's wrong." Why do you feel this is wrong? It's a passed prop and the consuming component can make zero assertions on its reference stability. As Diesel correctly points out though, you can memoize the callback the parent passes to children.

Comment: Because everything I've read says this is not a valid instance in which I should exclude the value from the dependency array.

Comment: Ah, I interpreted your comment as you were questioning the linter and felt *it* was wrong. I see.

Comment: Gotcha! No, I meant that the behavior of ignoring the linter would be wrong. Yeah, that's unclear. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I go about fixing this? Can I tell the child to only use a
> static version of this function somehow?

Yep!

So, if `props.updateFilter` is included in the dependency array, you have issues. You call that function and it causes your parent component to re-render. And guess what? The parent creates a new `updateFilter` function (it does the same thing, but it makes a new one, the reference to the function is a new value which is all `React` checks). This causes the child to re-render, which causes your `useEffect` to run because its dependency is a new function. That's bad!

So... add `useCallback`

```
function updateFilter = useCallback((filterStatus) => {
    ...
    setStateVal(filterStatus);
}, []);
```

`useCallback` creates the function one time, and only makes a new reference if its dependencies change (as it should). It has a little bit more overhead, but if I'm ever unsure I use it.

Also, bonus, after dealing with these issues, I use the `setState(previousValue => previousValue + 1)` form much more than `setState(previousValue + 1)` as it has many benefits. `previousValue` doesn't have to be in the dependency array and multiple `setState`s can be stacked in one render cycle (instead of using the initial value).

Comment: You're an absolute hero. Worked like a charm. I've read about useCallback along with the rest, but kinda just went over my head so I missed that it was perfect for this situation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped! I you have questions on it let me know. You'll read a lot of articles that say don't over use `useCallback`. I don't think the cost is that high and I use it unless I absolutely know it's okay to create a new function each time.